# How to validate a form field which must be double and not empty in Struts 2

Tags: validation, struts2

How can I validate a form field which must be double and not empty in Struts 2 using XML file ?

I tried this but it doesn't validate the field empty value.

[image: my XML validation file]

Answer (score 0):

You can place many validators on the field like

```xml
 <validators>
   <!-- Field Validator Syntax -->
    <field name="doulevalue">
        <field-validator type="required">
               <message>doulevalue must not be null</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="double">
            <param name="minExclusive">0.123</param>
            <param name="maxExclusive">99.98</param>
            <message>Percentage needs to be between ${minExclusive} and ${maxExclusive} (exclusive)</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

all of them will be executed in the order provided in xml, until you define a short-circuit attribute, which break the execution of other validators on the error.